# Can't login after choosing "Diagnostic startup" in msconfig?

Tags: windows-10, login

I wanted to test something in Diagnostic startup mode. For some reason upon reboot, my PC showed my account picture with an error saying "Something happened and you PIN isn't available.  Click to set up you PIN again." When I click on Set up my PIN, there is a pause, then I get the same message again.  When I click on it again, I often get a dialog window saying "Search for app in the store"  but if I choose yes, nothing happens.

[I've Googled and found this thread with no answer.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/help-i-put-msconfig-into-diagnostic-startup-how-do/42f97780-a1c7-4d51-ab23-0f9a14285f14?auth=1)

I've rebooted into Safe Mode using the Recovery Reboot Screen with no luck.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK To fix this specific issue, I had to do the following:

1. Hold Shift and click the power icon, choose "Restart" and wait until you see the blue Windows recovery screen.
2. [Choose "Advanced" and choose Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOZAz.png)
3. You'll restart and you should be put to a screen where it asks you for your MS Password. Input that and you should get a Command Prompt.
4. Input the following commands:
5. `move c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe c:\`
6. `copy c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe`
7. Restart your computer.
8. On the login screen, now [click the "Ease of Use" icon at the bottom-right next to the Power button.](https://www.wimware.com/design/how-to/windows-10-password-reset-cmd/reset-windows-10-admin-password-cmd-9.jpg)
9. A command prompt will open.
10. Type "msconfig"
11. Change the "Startup Selection" to "Normal Startup"
12. Restart the computer.

From there you should be able to log in with your PIN as usual. The last step is to clean-up what you did  and re-enable accessibility:

1. Open a folder explorer and go to `C:\`
2. Copy the "Utilman.exe" file from there into the `C:\Windows\System32\` folder
3. It'll ask for administrator privileges, Continue, and you should be back to normal.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me! thank you!

Comment: Thanks. To restore, I used cmd with admin privileges to copy the original file back to system32. The Explorer method was giving me errors.

Comment: Works like a charm! Just remember that while you are moving/copying files in Recovery Mode your Windows installation may be accessible under different drive letter than C. In my case it was D.

Comment: You are legit a life saver brother!

Comment: did not work for me. In step 8 it would not open the command prompt. clicking on the ease of use did nothing (nothing, not even options for contrast, magnifier etc)
I think a possible difference was that have windows 10, not the same one as in the picture :-(

Comment: But after some figuring out I manage to use bios connect and reset my laptop keeping files.
So far seem good, actually remembering my account and pin and I am now past the login screen. I lost my customisable setting but the files are still there ;-)

Comment: This worked for me, on Win 11. My problem originated when I went to msconfig (Win+R>msconfig) and selected Diagnostic Startup with all default settings.  I immediately restarted my PC to find that I could not log in.

Comment: The whole "enter your password" part is the hangup for me on these solutions. I have this problem on a new Windows install, and I have only ever logged in with a pin. In this case Windows seems to not have and cannot obtain the password. Awesome... Windows destroyed by diagnostic startup.

Comment: @DAG I know you use a PIN, but the account you're using is linked to a Microsoft Account, right? That's what password you should be using here. If you are using a local only account, then I'm not sure what happens. If you make any progress on this and figure out how to get past that password screen, please share!

Comment: @NessDan I ended up re-installing Windows. Ouch. Yes it's my MS account and password... which I use everywhere all the time. On re-install I noticed something particularly strange, I was never once asked for my password. Windows sent an approval to my phone. This further confirms my suspicion that this is a bug. If you happen to only have 1 account on the PC... and it's a MS account... and you never type your pw in... and you get stuck in the diag startup... you're out of luck.

Comment: I, too, fell prey to Microsoft's sloppy engineering today, and I can confirm that this approach still works on 22H2. You just have to use the option to boot without early anti-malware protection because Windows Defender (?) deletes Utilman.exe if it doesn't match some expected signature. I'm genuinely baffled by Windows 10 having several configuration options that quite literally brick the computer, and the only feasible fix requires you to use this ancient hack. Seriously, WTF, Microsoft?!

Comment: Great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I didn't try the other answer because it seemed super risky to move .exe files in System32 around, but I found another solution that only involves [disabling the "pin-only" sign-on via RegEdit in Windows Recovery mode](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1345153-unable-to-logon-to-windows-with-message-something-happened-and-your-pin-isnt-available-click-to-set-up-your-pin-again/). This is I think a much less risky solution (and worked for me). Full credit to ramava on LTT for figuring this out. I'm pasting that answer below verbatim in case the link above breaks eventually:

> This happened to me last night and I want to document it here so that
> hopefully someone else won't have to spend 3 hours trying to fix it
> through trial and error, or worse, have to "Reset my PC" or reinstall,
> which I was very close to doing before I solved it. Then later, I
> recreated the problem on a virtual machine  of a fresh Windows 10
> install to see which thing I did actually fixed it and discovered
> another potential problem that people may encounter. This may not
> solve the problem completely if it was originally caused by something
> different than my problem, but hopefully it'll be a good head start
> for those people.
>
> The Problem:
>
> The problem is caused by a sign-in setting for Microsoft accounts in
> later builds of Windows 10 that prevents you from using a regular
> password to logon, but doesn't work at all if the services that make
> Windows Hello work aren't running. This setting is enabled by default.
>
> [image: THDrKnU.png]
>
> For me, this happened because I enabled Diagnostic Startup in
> msconfig. This disabled all the required services and then I couldn't
> logon because the only account on the computer was made using a
> Microsoft Account instead of a local account.
>
> [image: WHMh7BC.png]
>
> After pressing ok and rebooting, I was presented with this:
>
> [image: aMPvaEF.png]
>
> The Solution:
>
> First, hold down Shift while pressing restart on the logon screen.
> This will bring up the Recovery options on reboot.
>
> [image: dQSdeY0.png]
>
> Click Troubleshoot -> Advanced Options -> Command Prompt.
>
> [image: lKYGaGd.png]
>
> [image: elpIgMC.png]
>
> [image: GSIZlpv.png]
>
> You may be asked to log in at this point, which I think depends on
> your which build of Windows it is. It did use the password and didn't
> seem to have any trouble on the one machine that required me to do it.
> The much newer preview build never asked for one.
>
> Run regedit.
>
> [image: kX4aEFC.png]
>
> This will bring up the registry for the recovery environment (WinRE),
> not your install of Windows. So you have to manually load the registry
> hive to be able to edit them. To do that, first select
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, then select File -> Load Hive... from the menu.
>
> [image: VnQdFst.png]
>
> The hive files will be in C:\Windows\System32\config (or in the case
> of one of my computers, it was E:). Load the SOFTWARE hive file. It
> will ask you for a name. I normally just use an extra s in front of
> the name, but it really doesn't matter as long as it's not something
> that's already there. This will give us a new listing under HKLM. My
> instructions will assume you name them ssoftware and ssystem like I
> do.
>
> (Note: Don't use the version on the X:\ drive. It's the registry from
> the stripped down version of Windows that you're currently using to
> fix this.)
>
> [image: TKt0Wlt.png]
>
> [image: ZpUpy7C.png]
>
> Solution #1:
>
> Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ssoftware\Microsoft\Windows
> NT\CurrentVersion\PasswordLess\Device. There there is a key for
> DevicePasswordLessBuildVersion. Change the value from 2 to 0. This
> will turn off that "Require Windows Hello" setting.
>
> Now reboot. If you're lucky, you can now logon with your password, and
> then hopefully fix whatever is causing the issue. In my case, it was
> just going back to Normal Startup in msconfig.
>
> If it tells you that your password is incorrect (even though it's the
> right password), that means the password has never actually been used
> before and we have to do some extra steps.
>
> Solution #2:
>
> To make this work, we need to enable some logon services for Microsoft
> Accounts and make sure network access is enabled by enabling services.
>
> Reboot back to the WinRE command prompt and open regedit again. This
> time, we'll load the SYSTEM hive as ssystem.
>
> Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ssystem\ControlSet001\Services, we're going
> to go to each service and edit the Start key value. For reference, the
> valid values for startup type here are:
>
> ```
> 0: Boot
> 1: System
> 2: Automatic
> 3: Manual
> 4: Disabled
> ```
>
> [image: cTYiPKF.png]
>
> The short name is where you'll find it in the registry, in parenthesis
> is the long name for it. Some of these may seem unnecessary, but they
> are dependencies for other services.
>
> These services need to be set to Manual startup (Start = 3):
>
> ```
> lmhosts                (TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper)
> Netman                (Network Connections)
> VaultSvc            (Credential Manager)
> Wecsvc                (Windows Event Collector)
> WbioSrvc            (Windows Biometric Serviced)
> wlidsvc                (Microsoft Account Sign-in Assistant)
> ```
>
> And these services need to be set to Automatic startup (Start = 2):
>
> ```
> Dhcp                    (DHCP Client)
> EventLog                (Windows Event Log)
> EventSystem            (COM+ Event System)
> LanmanServer            (Server)
> LanmanWorkstation        (Workstation)
> NlaSvc                (Network Location Awareness)
> nsi                    (Network Store Interface Service)
> SamSs                    (Security Accounts Manager)
> ```
>
> Reboot. Hopefully, Windows will now be able to contact Microsoft's
> servers and validate your password so you can logon.

Comment: I'd argue it is much riskier to mess with regedit. The accepted answer safely swaps executables (keeping a backup of the original) and safely swaps them back. The reason is to have the available button (accessibility) trigger the executable we need access to (cmd.exe) to run the tools we need (msconfig) to get out of the mess in the same way we got into it. Of course, all this wouldn't be necessary if MS just offered a "Restart Normally" option in the power menu.

Comment: IMO, your answer is useful in isolating the Windows hello option as the culprit, but is indeed much riskier than the simple copy of Utilman suggested in the accepted answer. Manually loading and mucking with a registry is beyond terrifying.