# Messed with Regedit trying to recover PC! What settings changes affect my PC negatively?

Tags: data-recovery, windows-11, wifi-configuration, regedit, default-settings

**Hello everyone! This is a second post I found in my drafts (luckily) after my newer post got closed for vagueness.**

### Setup:

I was recently victim to being locked out of my PC thanks to MSconfig's diagnostic mode and while I was trying to fumble my way out of it with different solutions I did some other solutions. I'm wondering how to turn these settings back to default/what would happen if I left them like this (if this is relevant, I stream on Twitch and stuff, so I don't want to compromise my computer's safety of course).

### My PC:

Alienware Aurora (I think R8)

- Windows 11
- i5-9400 CPU
- 16 GB RAM
- RTX 2060

## What I did:

> Note: I don't exactly remember the order of things and everything I did, but I believe that the things I remember are the most relevant and is done in order.

1. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1743505/1758303)

In this step, it makes you go into regedit and change some settings around. This is the big thing I'm worried about currently: what did I do? (Check the "The Question(s) heading for more info). I may have made a mistake but don't really remember one besides accidentally being in the wrong drive for some of the beginning steps.

2. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8ABl5WFmPw)

> I messed up somewhere during this process. I believe I accidently put `copy *-* backup` instead of `copy *.* backup` and then hastily did it correctly multiple times just in case (lol). I might've done it at the `copy *-* ..` step, but I'm pretty sure it was at the other step. After doing that I re-do the thing right and then continue. My PC had 11 things after I overwrote a file and then 12 I believe, which confused me.

3 (The solution). [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1639847/1758303)

## The Question(s)

During this process of recovering my computer, it is apparent that I made some mistakes and followed some incorrect solutions that changed settings on my pc when I stumbled through regedit. Are these settings changes important? What do they change? Should I/How do I change them back? What are the excess folders for? Should I/How do I fix that?

Thanks.

P.S.: If you need more information please ask! I'm happy to give more info where I can, but my memory isn't perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The Registry is (a) a very technical tool and (b) very unforgiving.

If you cannot back out your changes exactly, then truly the best thing you can do is to back up all your documents and email to an external drive.

Then install Windows 11 as it normally installs.

I have been using Windows 11 Pro for 18 months now.

Comment: Besides messing up the registry, is there anything else (e.g. the settings changes in the first answer) that would prompt me to backup and redownload? I have run some commands to restore any corrupt windows files and my computer seems to be fine. Is that superficial?